# how to round date format on x axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a curve in between two others filled and as soon as I have these two "plots", my x-axis become strange.

Here is my MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import datetime
import numpy as np

dates=[u'0600', u'0630', u'0700', u'0730', u'0800', u'0830', u'0900', u'0930', u'1000', u'1030']#["0800","0830","0900"]

x=[datetime.datetime.strptime(h,'%H%M') for h in dates]
y=np.arange(len(x))
tmin=y/2.
tmax=y*2.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y,'r')
ax.fill_between(x,tmin,tmax)

hfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with bad x-axis]

where the x-axis should looks like

[image: Plot with good x-axis]

which can easily be obtained by commenting one of the `plot` or `fill_between` command line.

Any idea of how to have the second x-axis in the first figure ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would probably be to use

```
ax.x_axis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,30]))
```

Comment: Ok, that solve the output. But I still don't understand why it appends.

Comment: Appends what? I don't understand the question

Comment: The point is that matplotlib modify automatically the `xtickslabel` so the rounded numbers became 29 or 59. This append if I have these two plots while there is no problem if I plot only one of of theme (`plot` or `fill_between`)

Comment: I assume that the automatic range calculation reacts in some way, shifting the lower limit slightly to the left. As a consequence the tick locations shift. Contrary to normal numbers, you formatter does not round but will always remove all lower-resolution information.

Comment: I agree, but why does it shift my axis when I add a plot ? It seems like a bug !

Comment: In fact, it does the same if I use a classical range as x data. The automatic range calculation became wider